# Tiering pandas column based on unique id and range cutoffs

Tags: python, pandas

I have one df that categorizes income into tiers across males and females and thousands of zip codes. I need to add a column to df2 that maps each person's income level by zip code (average, above average etc.).

The idea is to assign the highest cutoff exceeded by a given person's income, or assign to lowest tier by default

The income level for each tier also varies by zip code. For certain zip codes there are limited number of tiers (e.g. no very high incomes). There are also separate tiers for males by zip code not shown due to space.

I think I need to create some sort of dictionary, not sure how to handle this. any help would go a long way, thanks.

**Edit: The first df acts as a key, and I am looking to use it to assign the corresponding row value from the column 'Income Level' to df2

E.g. for a unique id in df2, compare df2['Annual Income'] to the matching id in df['Annual Income cutoff']. Then assign the highest possible Income level from df as a new row value in df2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['female',10009,'very high',10000000],['female',10009,'high',100000],['female',10009,'above average',75000],['female', 10009, 'average', 50000]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sex', 'Area Code', 'Income level', 'Annual Income cutoff'])
print(df)

      Sex  Area Code   Income level  Annual Income cutoff
0  female      10009      very high              10000000
1  female      10009           high                100000
2  female      10009  above average                75000
3  female      10009        average                 50000

data_2 = [['female',10009, 98000], ['female', 10009, 56000]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['Sex', 'Area Code', 'Annual Income'])
print(df2)

      Sex  Area Code  Annual Income
0  female      10009          98000
1  female      10009          56000

output_data = [['female',10009, 98000, 'above average'], ['female', 10009, 56000, 'average']]
final_output = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns = ['Sex', 'Area Code', 'Annual Income', 'Income Level'])
print(final_output)

      Sex  Area Code  Annual Income   Income Level
0  female      10009          98000  above average
1  female      10009          56000        average
```

Comment: Sorry, first time posting I am seeing some of the outputs are off -- hopefully this is readable

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is a bit confusing, could you perhaps [edit] to include more detail about which of your provided sample dataframes are input vs output, and how to map your input sample to your output sample?

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for the feedback I tried to edit my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `pd.merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('Annual Income'), 
              df.sort_values('Annual Income cutoff'), 
              left_on = 'Annual Income', 
              right_on = 'Annual Income cutoff',
              by=['Sex', 'Area Code'], direction = 'backward')
```

Output:

```
      Sex  Area Code  Annual Income Income level  Annual Income cutoff
0  female      10009          56000      average                 50000
1  female      10009          98000      average                 50000
```